# Upper- or lower-casing input based on the case of the first character

Tags: expl3, latex3, l3regex, textcase

For some sequence of characters, I want to change the case of all characters to match that of the first. So for example, `aBCD → abcd` and `Abcd → ABCD`.

My naïve attempt to do this in LaTeX3 did not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\regex_const:Nn \capitals {[A-Z]}

\cs_new:Npn \change_case:n #1 {
  \tl_head:n {#1}
  \regex_match:NnTF \capitals {\tl_head:n {#1}}
    {\tl_use:N \tl_upper_case:n {\tl_tail:n {#1}}}
    {\tl_use:N \tl_lower_case:n {\tl_tail:n {#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\change_case:n {aBcD}~ \change_case:n {AbcD}

\end{document}
```

This gave the output of `aBCD ABCD` instead of the expected `abcd ABCD`.

It seems like there must be something obvious I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `\tl_use:N` to do but it's not correct (albeit harmless) to use it before a function. The only (?) use case for `\tl_use:N` is before a variable to indicate unambiguously that you intend to ‘use’ the contents of the variable at that point in time. E.g., `\tl_use:N \c_string_tl` will print a space. `\tl_use:N` also serves as a basis for `\tl_use:c`, which is a more useful function in its own right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expand the argument before doing the regex, else it is just looking at it as-is and `\tl_head:n` is not in your list of capitals.

[Somebody please correct me if this explanation is hopelessly naïve.]

Please do read the naming guidelines for expl3. Although your code will work even if you violate them, there are very strong reasons not to do so. In essence, as I understand their purpose, the syntax is designed to avoid the conflicts which plague 2e and improve the consistency and, therefore, transparency of code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_const:Nn \c_kevin_capitals_regex {[A-Z]}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \keven_change_case:n #1 {
  \tl_head:n {#1}
  \regex_match:NxTF \c_kevin_capitals_regex {\tl_head:n {#1}}
    {\text_uppercase:n {\tl_tail:n {#1}}}
    {\text_lowercase:n {\tl_tail:n {#1}}}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:NnTF {NxTF}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keven_change_case:n {aBcD}~ \keven_change_case:n {AbcD}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image: abcd/ABCD]

Comment: I think it would be better to use `f` expansion rather than `x` expansion because it suffices to expand the `\tl_head:n` and won't break if the argument contains fragile macros.

Comment: @HoodChatham In light of the OP's other questions, I suspect that `x` is going to be needed here because the OP wants the processing done from the inside out when things are nested, and that's going to require `x` rather than `o`. However, if I'm wrong about the OP's use-case, then `o` would indeed be better. (At least, I think it'll require `x`.)

Comment: @HoodChatham However, my names were all wrong, of course, as I didn't think to check them.

Comment: Yeah everyone expects things to be done inside out. I'm just wary of `\edef`ing content that is intended to be typeset -- it seems to me that you should at least use `\protected@edef` here.

Comment: @HoodChatham I don't see that `o` is really much improvement over `x` in that case, though. Either way, there could be stuff in the stream which the user wants `\protect`ed. Or am I confused?

Comment: Oh I see I'm being dumb. Since `\tl_head` returns only the first token of `#1`, a problem can only occur if the first token is something problematic, but then it won't be an upper or lowercase letter and so won't be valid input to this function anyway.